How to generate the Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$ from the state $|00\rangle$ using Qiskit?
I want to generate the Bell state $(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ from the state $|00\rangle$ in qiskit, applying the Hadamard gate followed by the $\text{CNOT}$ gate.
But it generates $(|11\rangle-|00\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. What is the problem?
sv1 = Statevector.from_label('01')
mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(2)
mycircuit1.h(0)
mycircuit1.cx(0,1)
new_sv1 = sv1.evolve(mycircuit1)
print(new_sv1)
plot_state_qsphere(new_sv1.data)


Qiskit uses little-endian ordering for both classical bits and qubits. So, the least significant bit (LSB) is the rightmost bit in the binary representation of numbers. That means, you should use
sv1 = Statevector.from_label('10')

instead of
sv1 = Statevector.from_label('01')

For more details, see the documentation.

The Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$ can be generated from $|00\rangle$ in Qiskit as follows:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

sv1 = Statevector.from_label('00') # start with |00>

mycircuit1 = QuantumCircuit(2)
mycircuit1.h(0)
mycircuit1.cx(0,1)

mycircuit1.x(0) # apply x gate after CNOT

new_sv1 = sv1.evolve(mycircuit1)
display(mycircuit1.draw('mpl'))
display(new_sv1.draw('latex'))


Regarding your code, I see two possible issues for which I included in-line comments in my code. The first issue is that you are starting with $|01\rangle$ instead of $|00\rangle$. The second issue is that if you start with $|00\rangle$, then the $H$ and $CX$ gates are not enough. You also need an $X$ gate at the end.
